# Issue importing css file in react component

Tags: reactjs, import, babeljs

I'm getting an issue with this code:

```
Import styles from '.treeView.css'

React.createClass({
   render(
     <div styleName={styles.treeNode>some text </div>
   );
});
})
```

My css is :

`.treeNode { color:red }`

This runs fine when running webpack with the css-loader.  However I can no longer run my tests that import the above component as it complains about
"unexpected token" starting on line 1 of the css file.

My npm test line in package.json is

```
mocha './src/**/*.tests.js' --compilers js:babel-core/register
```

I'm not certain whether this is an issue with my babel setup not being able to parse the css file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket on your `styleName` prop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocha testing failed due to css in webpack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236443/mocha-testing-failed-due-to-css-in-webpack)

Answer (score 0):

it should be

`<div styleName={styles.treeNode}>some text </div>`but not

`<div styleName={styles.treeNode>some text </div>`